# How to change the accent color of a compact date UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a compact date UIPickerView created in Storyboard as shown below. How can I change the blue accent color in the calendar pop-up to a different color? I've tried changing the tint color of the element in Storyboard, and that just changes color of the "Nov 4, 2021" text.

Also, is there any way to change the unselected black color of the current date to something else?

[image: UIPickerView]

Comment: `UIDatePicker.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orange`

Comment: Thank you so much! You should've just put that as an answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jnpdx!

```
UIDatePicker.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orange
```